# Expose FastAPI on two different ports

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I want to scrape some metrics from my FastAPI server. However, I do not want to show it to the public in contrast to the remaining API.

Hence, I resolved to create a second server and tried to run (inspired by this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69641363/how-to-run-fastapi-app-on-multiple-ports)):

```py
app = FastAPI()
app2 = FastAPI()

app2.mount("/metrics", metrics_app)
```

and then set it up with docker-compose like this

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  scraiber_gpt:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 & uvicorn app.main:app2 --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
      - 8005:8001
```

However, I cannot see anything from app2.

Is there some way to make it work?

Comment: Can you have a look in the container and see if app2 is actually running?

Comment: Don't run 2 apps, just mount the metrics on a separate port

Comment: @azro Many thanks for your inpute. Do you have an example at hand, how I can accomplish that?

Comment: what is `metrics_app` object ?

Comment: Do the simple http technique https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#http with a custom port

Comment: Do you mean the ones for FastAPI? Because that is the ones I tried ... or the more generic one at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the command `uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 & uvicorn app.main:app2 --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001`, which runs the first `uvicorn` command and waits for that to finish, which it doesn't, since it's a server application.

If you want to expose two applications on different ports, and you're already running docker compose, the easiest thing would be to could start two containers:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  scraiber_gpt:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000

  metrics:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: uvicorn app.main:app2 --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8005:8000
```

If you are running behind nginx or a similar reverse proxy, another solutionn would be to run everything in one `FastAPI` app, and then only expose the routes you want publically available to external requests.

Comment: many thanks for your reply. However, the metrics for `app2` relate to `app`, so does your approach still work then?